# Google DataFlow python pipeline write failure

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm running a simple DataFlow pipeline w/ the Python SDK for counting keywords. The job runs fine for pre-processing the input data, but it fails for grouping/output steps with the following error.

I guess the logs says the worker is having an issue accessing the temp folder, but the storage bucket in our project exists with proper permissions. What could be a possible issue for this?

```
 "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcsio.py", line
 606, in write raise self.upload_thread.last_error # pylint:
 disable=raising-bad-type HttpError: HttpError accessing
 <https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/[PROJECT-NAME-REDACTED]-temp-2016-08-07_04-42-52/o?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&name=0015bf8d-fa87-4c9a-82d6-8ffcd742d770>:
 response: <{'status': '404', 'alternate-protocol': '443:quic',
 'content-length': '165', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'server':
 'UploadServer', 'x-guploader-uploadid':
 'AEnB2UoYRPUwhz-OXlJ437k0J8Uxd1lJvTsFbfVJF_YMP2GQEvmdDpo7e-3DVhuqNd9b1A_RFPbfIcK6hCsFcar-hdI94rqJZUvATcDmGRRIvHecAt5CTrg',
 'date': 'Sun, 07 Aug 2016 04:43:23 GMT', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443";
 ma=2592000; v="36,35,34,33,32,31,30"', 'content-type':
 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{ "error": { "errors": [
 { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found" }
 ], "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" } } >
```

Comment: The bucket name `[PROJECT-NAME-REDACTED]-temp-2016-08-07_04-42-52` looks incorrect. Do you have a `TextFileSink`? What are the arguments you are passing to it, is it a valid gcs location?

Comment: I can reproduce this with the unmodified wordcount example. Setting the output as `gs://mybucket` fails whereas `gs://mybucket/` works. In case you do not have it adding the last slash might resolve your problem.

Comment: @SzereDyeri Yes, I set a legitimate GCS location. BTW, by repeating 5 times the same pipeline with exactly same command line arguments, the task finally succeeded. I guess this is not only an issue with bucket names, but there should be some other issue with DataFlow.

Comment: Was it exactly the same code and command line for the all five times? From the error log you posted, it looks like the temp file location was not correctly constructed. Same thing should have happened on all tries.

Comment: @SzereDyeri Yup, exactly the same code and the same command. This is why I'm saying that there could be some other issue with DataFlow. The GCS bucket that I used is a legitimate one that I had used for other pipelines successfully before this incident. I think, for some reason, the prior 4 executions couldn't locate the GCS bucket internally. Please let me know if you need these job IDs to investigate the issue further.

Comment: Thank you for details, that is interesting. If you would like to share one of the job ids I would like to investigate further. Although I cannot promise whether this would lead to a resolution or not.

Comment: @SzereDyeri Thank you! One of the failed jobs is: 

2016-08-06_21_40_03-13346675036861094373

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you. It is definitely a case of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-539 . I could not find more specific information from the job id. Using sub-directories (instead of the root of gcs buckets) as arguments for TextFileSink's should help with issue in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

This is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-539, which doesn't allow root buckets as outputs for TextFileSink.  As a workaround, please use a subdirectory path (e.g. gs://foo/bar) as output locations.